# Expo Local Authentication on Android skipping Face Authentication

Tags: react-native, expo, android-biometric-prompt

I am trying to implement biometric authentication in a react native app using expo local authentication.
Everything seems to works on iPhone and Android EXCEPT that expo's authenticateAsync function skips Face Authentication on Android.

Among my installed packages are

- "expo": "~47.0.9",
- "expo-local-authentication": "~13.0.2",

I am using Expo Go and a development build to test the app on a device running Android 10.

My app is using expo local authentication to check for hardware support for biometric authentication and if enabled use biometric authentication.

When I run a development build on my Android phone and console log the results of

```
LocalAuthentication.supportedAuthenticationTypesAsync()
```

I get [1,2] which confirms that my device supports both fingerprint and facial recognition. And yes, face authentication has been set up on my device.

However, the authenticateAsync function always skips facial recognition and either

1. requests the user's PIN code (if fingerprint is not set up)  or
2. requests fingerprint authentication (if enabled).

I wonder if this is a bug or if I am missing something, e.g. in my app config.

I have modifed my app.config.js as specified in the expo docs but this should only be relevant for Ios devices anyway:

```
{
  "expo": {
    "plugins": [
      [
        "expo-local-authentication",
        {
          "faceIDPermission": "Allow $(PRODUCT_NAME) to use Face ID."
        }
      ]
    ]
  }
}
```

I appreciate any help and comments and I am happy to provide more information if it is deemed helpful. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

As per the expo documentation, Expo LocalAuthentication allows you to use the Biometric Prompt on Android or Face ID and Touch ID on iOS to authenticate the user.

Doc: https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/local-authentication/